# Why psycopg2 returns same result for repeated SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

When I execute ordinary Select correct results are returned, but when I execute this select for DB uptime it returns same first result all the time. I did check Postgres logs and I see that select is executed.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3

    import psycopg2
    from time import sleep

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='MyDB' user='root' host='127.0.0.1' password='********'")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    def test():
        e = 0
        while e != 100:
            cur.execute("SELECT date_trunc('second', current_timestamp - pg_postmaster_start_time()) as uptime;")
            uptv = cur.fetchone()
            print(uptv)
            e += 1
            sleep(0.1)

    test()
```

Comment: is `autocommit` off?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Per the documentation, `current_timestamp` returns the timestamp *at the start of the transaction*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). This behaviour is required by the SQL standard.

`psycopg2` begins a transaction when you run a query. It does not autocommit. So unless you `conn.commit()`, the same xact is running for the first query and your later iterations.

You should:

- `conn.commit()` after each query (or if you like, `conn.rollback()` if it's read only and makes no changes); or
- Use `clock_timestamp()` instead of `current_timestamp`, since the former changes throughout the transaction.

It's best to avoid leaving transactions running anyway, as they can tie up resources the server needs.